# Centering Figure issue

Tags: center, picture-mode

I am still new in Latex and have some difficulty centering a figure from MATLAB. As you can see the code from MATLAB prints perfectly on Latex so does the picture. However, I use `\centering` and `\begin{center}` but it did not do the job.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%For type of paper
\usepackage{authblk}%For author commands
\usepackage{setspace}% For double space
\doublespacing% For double space
\usepackage{subeqnarray} % For number equations (1a), (1b) etc.
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf} % For including graphics
\usepackage[framed , numbered]{matlab-prettifier}% For MATLAB code
\usepackage{amssymb}% For ams math, symbol packages
\usepackage{amsmath} % For more ams
\usepackage{nccmath}% For adding Mathematical commands
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins as needed
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1.50\textwidth]{fourierSeries.eps}
\centering
\end{figure}
\lstinputlisting[style = Matlab-editor]{fourierSeries.m}
\end{document}
```

Here is a code from MATLAB:

```matlab
function [ao,a,b] = fourierSeries(f,T,N)
  syms t;
  T = 2;
  wo = 2*pi/T;
  % heaviside(x-k) when k = 1, heaviside(x-1). it shifts the graph to the right.
  % when k = -1, for example, the graph is shift to the left.
  f = heaviside(t) - heaviside(t-1); 
  ao_sym = 1/T* int(f,t,0,T);
  ao = double(ao_sym);
  for n = 1:N;
    a_sym(n) = 2/T*int(f*cos(n*wo*t),t,0,T);
    b_sym(n) = 2/T*int(f*sin(n*wo*t),t,0,T);
    
    a(n) = double(a_sym(n));
    b(n) = double(b_sym(n));
  end
end
```

Comment: you are scaling the figure so it is 50% wider than the page `width=1.50\textwidth` so it can not possibly fit and can not be centred.

Comment: In any case your `centering` should come before the `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Use `\centering\makebox[0pt][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.50\textwidth]{fourierSeries.eps}}` instead.